# What does `(<-chan Delivery)(deliveries)` do?

Tags: go

I found this line:

```
return (<-chan Delivery)(deliveries), nil
```

https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/channel.go#L1089

What does it do? Why the double parentheses?

Comment: Good question and good find, I've never seen that written before.

Comment: td; I find ``(<-chan Delivery)(deliveries)``  more confusing than  ``<-chan Delivery(deliveries)``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). In your case, it converts `chan Delivery` (two-way channel of `Delivery` values) to `<-chan Delivery` (receive-only channel of `Delivery` values).

Answer (score 4):

It is a [type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Returns `deliveries` as a read-only channel.

Comment: The term 'read-only' channel is a bit misleading; it's is better understood as the 'read-end' of a channel (which has a 'write-end' also).

Answer (score 4):

Its a type conversion from two-way channel to send-only channel and in case you provide it can be omitted. Conversion would be done implicitly.